# Conditionally updating values in a dataframe column with null values

Tags: r

I'm wondering what's the cleanest way to do this. My source data has age set to 999 when it wasn't available, and I'd like to change it to null.

The obvious approach fails due to nulls

```
df[df$age=999,"age"] <- NA

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df$age > 100, "age", value = NA) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

Is this an appropriate use of which? It appears cleaner but I was cautioned against it:

```
df[which(df$age=999),"age"] <- NA
```

vs

```
df[df$age=999 & !is.na(df$age),"age"] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there 
try :

```
df$age[df$age==999] <- NA
```